# Database keyword missing error for MYOB ODBC in VBA

Tags: vba, odbc, myob

I'm a newbie VBA developer for my company and I'm trying to set up a **DSN-less connection string to our MYOB files** via the *MYOB ODBC*. 
I have followed the MYOB ODBC documentation in regards to the connection string and it currently looks like this:

```
ConnDetails.Open "Driver={MYOAU1001}; TYPE=MYOB; UID=TestUser; PWD; 
    DATABASE=C:\Reference\Test.MYO; HOST_EXE_PATH=C:\Premier19\Myobp.exe; 
    NETWORK_PROTOCOL=NONET; DRIVER_COMPLETION=DRIVER_NOPROMPT"
```

I am getting the error:
 `[MYOB ODBC]General error - Database keyword not present in the connect string`

I have searched online and haven't found anything that clarifies how to avoid this error or what it actually means, given that I have specified the database keyword within the string.

Any help on this matter is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in my case was a result of using `PWD;` instead of `PASSWORD=;`. 
The username I use **has no associated password** to access the MYOB file and the documentation advises that you can use PWD. 
It would seem this advice is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: +1 since it solved the issue. But one question: Did you try using `PWD=;` instead of `PWD;`?

Comment: @smagnan I just tried with `PWD=;` and it works fine. The documentation is written in such a way that it implies that `PWD;` is correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

### Possibility 1

I think `Driver` should be `DRIVER` because the case of the string keywords does matter.
 I don't know if it's the only error but it may be a reason.

EDIT: [Related topic](http://support.dataaccess.com/Forums/archive/index.php?t-3268.html) (see at the end)

### Possibility 2

From [MYOB ODBC errors](http://help11.simpro.co/?page_id=22068)

> **Error:** [HY000][MYOB ODBC] General error – Database keyword not present
>   in the connect string.
>
> **What caused it?** Most likely caused by the MYOB company file address
>   not existing in the Setup tab at the top of the accounting link.
>
> **Resolution:** Open the accounting link and on the setup tab, under “MYOB
>   company file” enter the address that links to the company file.

Tell me if any of this solves the issue. I found no link to the documentation pointing out that but it costs nothing to try.

Comment: I have corrected to 'DRIVER' and that has, sadly, made no difference. As for the accounting link setup, I can't find such an application and from what I can find online, they seem to be specific to external applications developed by third parties.

Comment: @Enrique I'm clearly not en expert on the topic, but maybe re-check that the DATABASE path is correct and that the HOST_EXE_PATH path is correct too ...

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason, using 'PWD;' when there is no password will not work. I replaced it with 'PASSWORD=;' and it works fine now.

Comment: Nice, wouldn't have guessed ... the error message isn't clear at all